# How to achieve this interface using Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have been working on a new Ember.js application and trying to create the interface below. I have the list and item view but I am struggling to understand how to structure the router so I can get sub-items to appear.

Is this something a component could handle or do I setup the controller to generate the view when an item is clicked?

Fairly new to Ember.js so excuse me if it is obvious.

Thanks!

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('login');
  this.route('admin', function() {
    this.route('list', function() {
      this.route('new');
      this.route('view', { path: '/:item_id/view'});
    });
  });
});
```

[image]

Comment: You can achieve this with a combination of named outlets and `Route#renderTemplate`

Comment: Hi Derek, that seems like a good structure for the router. For more useful feedback check out the [#-help channel on our Slack group](https://embercommunity.slack.com/messages/-help/).